# IPython notebook embedded on own webpage

Tags: python, ipython, tornado, jupyter-notebook

Does anybody has tried to integrate IPython notebook with own webpage? Are they any recipe about it? I don't mind to run separate tornado server I would just like to display the content inside the already existing application and I'm not sure if putting it inside the ifreme would be the best approach.

Comment: If you just want to display static content, you can use `ipython nbconvert` to convert notebooks to static HTML.

Comment: it's not really static content. I want to embed notebooks in the existing web application.

Comment: In that case iframes are probably the best way. But be careful with security: a running IPython notebook lets visitors run code on your server. You probably want to run the notebook server as a user with minimal privileges. If you want each visitor to have a separate namespace, you'll need something like [jiffylab](https://github.com/ptone/jiffylab) to allow that.